# Getting metadata of a post with Contact Form 7 form

Tags: wordpress, metadata, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 Wordpress plugin for my site.

Does anybody know how can I get the metadata of the post where the form is placed?

Tried with global $posts, etc. in some hooks, but the result is always NULL.

Comment: Do you want to populate fields of the CF7 form with meta data? If so this plugin might help https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I am not pretty sure if this plugin can do the job. What I am looking for is getting the metadata from the post where the form is placed using a shortcode, just before the form is send/saved in database.

Comment: @Faust are you want to get wordpress page meta data ? if yes then you can use this plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/

Comment: Nope. More precisely, I need to get the title of the post where the form is placed by shortcode ( example: [contact-form-7 id="33" title="Contact form 1"] ) and then store it in variable, just before form submission ( for example in 'wpcf7_before_send_mail' hook ). Nothing more than this and it would be good if it is possible to be done without plugin.

Comment: Do you want the page title to ne sent with the form or stored in the database? What are you looking to do with the title variable once you've stored it?

Comment: Use case: I create a form with a name, then copy the generated shortcode in a new post. What I want to do is, replace the title of the post that contains the form shortcode with that of the form. For example, if the post title is Test, and the form name is Contact Form, when the post with the form is shown it should be with the title Contact Form instead of Test. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I spent nearly whole day thinking about this little problem but finally I managed to solve it.

I used this filter 'wp_insert_post_data' which is executed on saving post data. The steps are following:

1. check if the post type is 'post', so the callback code is executed only in this case.
2. get post content, which contains the form shortcode (no other text in the post).
3. then use shortcode_parse_atts to got the form ID from there.
4. using the form ID, get the post data with get_post(), which contains the title and slug among the other parameters.
5. finally, set the current post's title and slug to the form title and slug.
6. happy face :)

The code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , 99, 2 );
function filter_post_data( $data , $post ) {
    if ( $data['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
        $content = stripslashes($data['post_content']);
        $attributes = shortcode_parse_atts($content);
        $post = isset($attributes['id']) ? get_post($attributes['id']) : "";

        if ( !empty($post) ) {
            $data['post_title'] = esc_html($post->post_title);
            $data['post_name'] = esc_html($post->post_name);    
        }   
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Maybe this is not the most beautiful solution, but it does the work. I hope someone will find it useful.

Once again, thanks to those that try to help in any way.